How to fix "invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=mold'" when compiling the Zed code editor from source?
I cloned the Zed code editor and tried running cargo build on my Arch Linux system, but I encountered the following error:
cargo build
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.86
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.12
   Compiling serde v1.0.208
   Compiling libc v0.2.158
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling version_check v0.9.5
   Compiling autocfg v1.3.0
   Compiling once_cell v1.19.0
   Compiling typeid v1.0.0
error: linking with clang failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/anaconda3/bin:/homeFolder/anaconda3/condabin:/homeFolder/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin:/homeFolder/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/homeFolder/.local/bin" VSLANG="1033" "clang" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcjA2Dag/symbols.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/serde-01e515355831dc5b/build_script_build-01e515355831dc5b.build_script_build.ae94dcb88509ea4f-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/serde-01e515355831dc5b/build_script_build-01e515355831dc5b.4m8dfrgjvoa7ni9sgqxxt70m2.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-52417a9a08ba8fb9.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-1b238e97929fdc18.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-3692c2663daa48a5.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-5c1e2d61611c0240.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-e55c5186b9bbabcb.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-7911d2fe92903c6c.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-c03510cdc48cfa52.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-7ec6f3765287c7b7.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-ab3f1b788cf79cfc.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-6db4226b4e34b1a6.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-f5bb1a38d410fa1e.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-e585efe74c64604d.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-03f8e93b59ffc316.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-669e9182bfe197a6.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-64b53226be979181.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-26921ac7e6a44d2b.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-6703049be165ebf1.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-04bfdf6b094564ce.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-6648dc218e522d87.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/serde-01e515355831dc5b/build_script_build-01e515355831dc5b" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs" "-fuse-ld=mold"
  = note: clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=mold'
          

error: could not compile serde (build script) due to 1 previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: linking with clang failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/anaconda3/bin:/homeFolder/anaconda3/condabin:/homeFolder/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin:/homeFolder/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/homeFolder/.local/bin" VSLANG="1033" "clang" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcSJr8pt/symbols.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-8eacb06089a9facd/build_script_build-8eacb06089a9facd.build_script_build.d370edbd5e99bc4f-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-8eacb06089a9facd/build_script_build-8eacb06089a9facd.build_script_build.d370edbd5e99bc4f-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-8eacb06089a9facd/build_script_build-8eacb06089a9facd.ava6gb48x3pvozhefupldarzi.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-52417a9a08ba8fb9.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-1b238e97929fdc18.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-3692c2663daa48a5.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-5c1e2d61611c0240.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-e55c5186b9bbabcb.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-7911d2fe92903c6c.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-c03510cdc48cfa52.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-7ec6f3765287c7b7.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-ab3f1b788cf79cfc.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-6db4226b4e34b1a6.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-f5bb1a38d410fa1e.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-e585efe74c64604d.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-03f8e93b59ffc316.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-669e9182bfe197a6.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-64b53226be979181.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-26921ac7e6a44d2b.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-6703049be165ebf1.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-04bfdf6b094564ce.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-6648dc218e522d87.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-8eacb06089a9facd/build_script_build-8eacb06089a9facd" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs" "-fuse-ld=mold"
  = note: clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=mold'
          

error: could not compile proc-macro2 (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: linking with clang failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/anaconda3/bin:/homeFolder/anaconda3/condabin:/homeFolder/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin:/homeFolder/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/homeFolder/.local/bin" VSLANG="1033" "clang" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcD8o9mf/symbols.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-581ad5a3700dd057/build_script_build-581ad5a3700dd057.build_script_build.4da90ae48cc40592-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-581ad5a3700dd057/build_script_build-581ad5a3700dd057.build_script_build.4da90ae48cc40592-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-581ad5a3700dd057/build_script_build-581ad5a3700dd057.build_script_build.4da90ae48cc40592-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-581ad5a3700dd057/build_script_build-581ad5a3700dd057.build_script_build.4da90ae48cc40592-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-581ad5a3700dd057/build_script_build-581ad5a3700dd057.dvblojldxtw1nxh9pj9jufrd0.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-52417a9a08ba8fb9.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-1b238e97929fdc18.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-3692c2663daa48a5.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-5c1e2d61611c0240.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-e55c5186b9bbabcb.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-7911d2fe92903c6c.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-c03510cdc48cfa52.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-7ec6f3765287c7b7.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-ab3f1b788cf79cfc.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-6db4226b4e34b1a6.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-f5bb1a38d410fa1e.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-e585efe74c64604d.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-03f8e93b59ffc316.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-669e9182bfe197a6.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-64b53226be979181.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-26921ac7e6a44d2b.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-6703049be165ebf1.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-04bfdf6b094564ce.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-6648dc218e522d87.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-581ad5a3700dd057/build_script_build-581ad5a3700dd057" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs" "-fuse-ld=mold"
  = note: clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=mold'
          

error: could not compile libc (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: linking with clang failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/homeFolder/anaconda3/bin:/homeFolder/anaconda3/condabin:/homeFolder/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin:/homeFolder/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/homeFolder/.local/bin" VSLANG="1033" "clang" "-m64" "/tmp/rustc6sF6kV/symbols.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-f55c78d799d41c74/build_script_build-f55c78d799d41c74.build_script_build.88e73112c11a4673-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-f55c78d799d41c74/build_script_build-f55c78d799d41c74.build_script_build.88e73112c11a4673-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-f55c78d799d41c74/build_script_build-f55c78d799d41c74.build_script_build.88e73112c11a4673-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-f55c78d799d41c74/build_script_build-f55c78d799d41c74.build_script_build.88e73112c11a4673-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-f55c78d799d41c74/build_script_build-f55c78d799d41c74.7o0ijdas9yyxsxztj7ehrxa4d.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-52417a9a08ba8fb9.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-1b238e97929fdc18.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-3692c2663daa48a5.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-5c1e2d61611c0240.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-e55c5186b9bbabcb.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-7911d2fe92903c6c.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-c03510cdc48cfa52.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-7ec6f3765287c7b7.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-ab3f1b788cf79cfc.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-6db4226b4e34b1a6.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-f5bb1a38d410fa1e.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-e585efe74c64604d.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-03f8e93b59ffc316.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-669e9182bfe197a6.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-64b53226be979181.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-26921ac7e6a44d2b.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-6703049be165ebf1.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-04bfdf6b094564ce.rlib" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-6648dc218e522d87.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/homeFolder/.rustup/toolchains/1.80-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/homeFolder/zed/target/debug/build/libc-f55c78d799d41c74/build_script_build-f55c78d799d41c74" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs" "-fuse-ld=mold"
  = note: clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=mold'
          

error: could not compile libc (build script) due to 1 previous error

I initially tried rustup component add cargo which had no effect and I still go the same error.

"[...] solved the issue for me" - If you are asking and self-answering, answers should be posted below and not in the question. However, even then the question itself should be clear and answerable by someone else. Your error message seems incomplete - in fact the contents omitted would describe clearly how "clang failed".

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

To solve this issue I installed mold via sudo pacman -S mold and the code successfully compiled

thanks for the advice @kmdreko , I've edited the post though if there any other issues or changes to be done please let me know

I had this exact issue on Ubuntu. The error message seems very similar to the error  I got. I'd say it is the Rust toolchain's fault, rather than OP's that the question is unclear. It is in there: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=mold'
